# OpenOffice - Combining multiple functions - Substring

Tags: function, sum, openoffice-calc, sumifs

I have a combination of functions I want to program in OpenOffice to look for a specific substring. Here's what I got:

```
=SUMIF(C3:C130;(LEFT(C3:C130;6)) = "String"; D3:D130)
```

To explain in words: Make a sum if the area C3:C130 contains the string "String" in the first 6 letters of the line. The numbers for the sum are in D3:D130.

For some reason I can't think of the solution right now. I think I'm missing some sort of "IF "String" equals "String" "-function here.
Could you point me in the right direction, please?
Much appreciated!

**edit01:** I just looked up the "LEFT"-function again and apparently I have that one wrong as well.

**How do I ask the function to check a line for a the value "String" as a part of a longer text?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that *[regular expressions are enabled for formulas](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Regular_Expressions_in_Calc)*: open menu `Tools` -> `Options` -> `OpenOffice Calc` -> `Calculate` -> `General Calculations`; check "`Enable regular expressions in formulas`".

Now, you can modify the formula as follows:

```
=SUMIF(C3:C130; "^String.*"; D3:D130)
```

The regular expression `^String.*` matches every cell beginning with `String`, using `^` for *[positional matching](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Regular_Expressions_in_Writer#Positional_match_.5E_.24_.5C.3C_.5C.3E)*. The last part of the expression `.*` matches every character following `String` if there is any.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. I know the placeholders for the most part but they didn't seem to work. Thanks for the help!